# Panda Dataframe comparing pairs of rows and if they pass move them to new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame and I want to compare column data with the data in the next row. I can see see how this is possible with loops but is there a better way to do this with pandas?

so for name - if the first two chars are the same as the first two chars in the name column of the next row. So is "SH" == "DR". Then I want to check if row 1 BS == row 2 BS... is sell == sell.

if a pair that matches the requirements is found they should then be dropped and added to a new DF.

```
   name  BS
1  SH-0  sell
2  DR-P  sell <-3 pairs meets conditions and move to new df
3  DR-0   buy <-
4  SH-P  sell <-
5  SH-0   buy <-
6  LI-0   buy
7  SH-P  sell <-
8  SH-0   buy <-
9  SH-P   buy

Result new df

   name   BS
1  DR-P  sell
2  DR-0   buy
3  SH-P  sell
4  SH-0   buy
5  SH-P  sell
6  SH-0   buy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from computing a *Series* containing first 2 chars from *name* column:

```
name2 = df.name[:].str[:2]
```

(to simplity the next statement, referring to these chars).

Then compute another *Series* holding indices of the first rows from
the "wanted" row pairs:

```
s = name2.eq(name2.shift(-1)) & name2.ne(name2.shift())\
    & df.BS.ne(df.BS.shift(-1))
```

Details:

- `name2.eq(name2.shift(-1))` - *name2* == *name2* in the next row,
- `name2.ne(name2.shift())` - *name2* != *name2* in the previous row,
- `df.BS.ne(df.BS.shift(-1))` - *BS* != *BS* in the next row.

And the final step is to retrieve the "wanted" rows:

```
df[df.index.isin(s[s].index.union(s[s].index + 1))]
```

Note the call to *union* to combine:

- "original" indices from *s* (indices of first rows in each pair),
- indices of second rows in each pair (original index + 1).

As you can notice, this solution is based on assumption that index values
in *df* are consecutive numbers (which is met in your case).

## How to drop "wanted" rows from the source *df*

Note *df.index.isin(s[s].index.union(s[s].index + 1))* indicates the "wanted"
rows (boolean indexing).
To generate a new DataFrame **and** drop them from *df*, proceed as follows:

1. Save indicated indices in a dedicated variable (*ind* in the code below).
2. Copy rows with these indices to a new DataFrame (*df2*).
3. Drop rows with these indices from the source *df* (in place).

The code to do it (instead of the last instruction above) is:

```
ind = df.index[df.index.isin(s[s].index.union(s[s].index + 1))]
df2 = df.loc[ind]
df.drop(ind, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help it's much appreciated. I'm also wondering how I can drop the items from the original list, but I can't quite seem to get it the code right.